# Bluez 5.28 - 5.37 "Not enough free handles to register service" issue with GATT (gatt_example plugin) services

Tags: 14.04, 15.10, bluetooth, services, bluez

I have tried to run **gatt_example plugin** from Bluez package in Ubuntu environment (14.04 LTS and 15.10). For that I have rebuild from source 5.37 (Ubuntu 14.04) and 5.35 (Ubuntu 15.10) with:

*$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-mode --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd*

And it I have ran **bluetoothd** via:

*sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=gatt_example -nEd*

However it works as expected only for version 5.27. Starting from 5.28 till latest 5.37 it does not work (registers only generic GATT services - all custom ones are **missed**). Logs shows issue:
"Not enough free handles to register service"

It looks similar to one mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891254/bluez-5-30-not-enough-free-handles-to-register-service-error-in-starting-blue.

Does anyone have faced such issues and how to fix them?